# Animate effect in jquery doesn't work properly

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to create a simple fading effect with jquery. Here is the link which show the example. The problem is it seems it doesn't work properly. Why?

http://jsbin.com/zijihugejowi/2/edit?html,css,js,output

Comment: Even if it would work, you should provide essential part of code here.

Comment: it works. it show you the example. At the top right you can see an edit in jsbin

Comment: What do you mean doesn't work properly? It fades out and in  http://jsfiddle.net/brxc9nrx/

Comment: The animation seems it takes place too late

Comment: @Anton the example you have provided it is slightly different from mine

Comment: whats your problem, its working fine..

Comment: @Mazzy Not really, i've just added a div so i could test the scroll.

Comment: when the jquery script is placed at the bottom of the page, the script should be wrapped in document.ready or something like $(function(){...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because animate chains too much when you scroll. Use code below for both lines

```
navbarBrandImg.stop().animate(/* your code */)
```

Also check this article about how bad is to use `.scroll()` directly

http://ejohn.org/blog/learning-from-twitter/

Comment: Just one more question. the script is at the bottom of the page. I shouldn't use document.ready. should I wrap it?

Comment: `document` triggers when all elements, css, js files e.t.c is loaded except images. `window` triggers after all files AND images loaded. If you need images to be loaded too, use window, otherwise document. Window may trigger late depend on visitors connection speed since it waits to load all images (could be some MBs).

Comment: I'm a little bit confused about where to place into the function.the script is placed at the bottom of the page. the page is full of images and the images is fixed and should appear when the user scroll down. if you were me, where would you wrap to the function?

Comment: @Mazzy always put css at the top, javascript at the bottom. For what to use it depends on your needs. Check this link for better explanation http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3698200/window-onload-vs-document-ready

Answer (score 0):

For that purpose, use fadeIn, fadeOut jQuery effects instead.

See working example here: [JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/zijihugejowi/3/edit)

Edit the following in your code:

CSS:

```
img {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
}
```

JS

```
if ($currWindow.scrollTop() > 100) {

    navbarBrandImg.fadeIn(500);

  } else {

    navbarBrandImg.fadeOut(500);
  }
```